# HTML make h-captcha form required in post form

Tags: html, hcaptcha

Hello I am currently trying to implement h-captcha into a html form in my website

However I noticed that by default its not "required" like for example text boxes can made to be

I havent found any good solutions out there who can help me out with this issue

Heres btw how I implement the h-captcha form itself

```
 <form action="/end" method="post">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         <div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="sitekey here" data-theme="dark"></div>
          <script src="https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js" async defer</script>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try importing the script in your header.

Answer (score 0):

Even when importing to the head. I also found with my form the same issue. You can leave the hcaptcha and still proceed to submit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33237438)